# Ionic http fail(response 0)

Tags: android, node.js, angular, api, ionic-framework

We are building an app which requires an API request. 
On front end we are using Ionic with Angular. When we tried to send a request to backend we get this error.

**It works when we are trying on desktop in browser.**

```
{
    "headers":{
        "normalizedNames":{

        },
        "lazyUpdate":null,
        "headers":{

        }
    },
    "status":0,
    "statusText":"Unknown Error",
    "url":"http://server_ip:3000/path/useCode/1234",
    "ok":false,
    "name":"HttpErrorResponse",
    "message":"Http failure response for http://server_ip:3000/path/useCode/1234: 0 Unknown Error",
    "error":{
        "isTrusted":true
    }
}
```

This is how we send a request.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

public sendCodeGET() {
    this.httpClient.get(`http://server_ip:3000/path/useCode/${this.code.trim()}`).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.response = JSON.stringify(res);
      },
      err => {
        this.response = JSON.stringify(err);
        this.presentToast(err.error['message']);
      }
    );
  }
```

We are using NodeJS v10.15.3 where we set CORS header presented below.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Content-Length,Content-Range");

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
```

config.cml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

We have also tried:
 - other API (https://coinmarketcap.com/api)
 - POST and GET requests

Comment: Check for your permission in AndroidManifest.xml.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, but i sorted it as below. Follow these steps

1. Open `[yourProject]/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

2.Add this line there `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

3.Add this line to `config.xml` file

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things I would suggest trying;

1. Download a CORS plugin that can allow you to bypass blocked headers
2. If you're using ionic I am assuming that this if for a hybrid app. Make use of ionic HTTP. You could get better results.
3. Check out Ionic's official docs for some help https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors